# Copy memory with offset in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory, copy

I want to copy a memory block with an offset, is it possible?

This is the code I have so far:

```
const
  SOURCE: array [0..5] of Byte = ($47, $49, $46, $38, $39, $61);
var
  Destination: Pointer;
begin
  // This is a full copy
  Move(SOURCE, Destination^, SizeOf(SOURCE));

  // If i want to copy from the third byte, is it possible?
  // I imagine the code should be, but it cannot be compiled.
  Move(Slice(SOURCE^, {Offset=}2)^, Destination^, SizeOf(SOURCE) - 2);
end;
```

Comment: When doing something like this, be aware that using SizeOf(Source) is usually a good way to create buffer overflows - you should always ensure the amount of data move fits the destination buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but it looks like

```
MoveMemory(pointer(NativeUInt(Destination) + 2), @SOURCE[0], SizeOf(SOURCE) - 2)
```

although I suspect you actually want

```
MoveMemory(pointer(NativeUInt(Destination) + 2), @SOURCE[2], SizeOf(SOURCE) - 2)
```

Comment: Notice that `Move` takes arguments `Source, Dest, Count`, while `MoveMemory` takes `Dest, Source, Count`. Also, the former wants identifiers, while the latter wants pointers.

Comment: Yes. @SOURCE[2] is exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: Andreas, why do you offset the destination with 2? I interpret the question as copy from source with offset 2 to destination. This is made with `MoveMemory( pt, @SOURCE[2],SizeOf(SOURCE)-2);` or `Move( SOURCE[2],pt^, SizeOf(SOURCE)-2);`.

Comment: @LU RD: Simply because I didn't quite understand what the OP meant.

Comment: Ok, I can live with that :) Just wanted to comment in case someone thought some pointer magic was needed, but it is not.

Answer (score 2):

To use `Move()` to copy a portion of the array, do it like this:

```
Move(SOURCE[Offset], Destination^, SizeOf(SOURCE)-Offset);
```